# Integrating Google Sign-In with WebView in Android

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, webview, oauth, google-oauth

Our Android app is a minimal wrapper around our mobile-friendly website. This is by design.

Google OAuth is one means by which users can authenticate. With [the announcement that WebView's will be blocked from Google OAuth](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html), we are now looking at how to move forward.

My current plan is:

1. Use a [`JavascriptInterface`](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript) to invoke native code when someone clicks on the web app's Sign in With Google button
2. Use [Google Sign In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/) to authenticate the user on the mobile app side.
3. Somehow send this authentication to the web server. Should I just redirect the user to the existing oauth callback URL?

Step 3 is where I'm not sure what the best approach is. It's a Ruby on Rails application using Omniauth.

Are there any examples of integrating Google Sign In with an almost entirely WebView-based application? Is this approach the right way to go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution described in [Authenticate with a backend server](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth) sounds just like what you want to do in step 3, though without using the OAuth callback URL.
Unfortunately, I could not find any reference on how to use it with OmniAuth.